# Is there a way to configure Jenkins to handle misfired jobs?

Tags: jenkins

I have a environment where I use Jenkins for launching Python scripts that are scheduled.

Let's say my server gets shutdown for two days for any reason. Is there a way to make Jenkins remember what tasks has not done these two days and automatically do them when it restarts?

Comment: I can't think of any mechanism that will do that. And honestly, I don't see the benefit. Imagine an office relocation. What is the server is shutdown for a month during relocation? Do you really want your server to be overburdened like that? Even if you give priority to new jobs, what would be the point?

Comment: Well, in this case for example it is necessary: I have to send data every day to my clients, if my server is shut down I still want that the data that hasn't been send to be sent  when the server is turned on. @hfontanez

Comment: So basically, there isn't any mechanism or maybe plugin that will do that in Jenkins right? @hfontanez

Comment: I haven't come across anything like that. Here's an alternative, instead of running `x` number of jobs per day lost, how about creating a report containing data for `x` number of days? Then, you can provide this report in a single job execution thread.

Comment: @hfontanez not valid in this case. Would you like to answer the question saying that there isn't any native mechanism in Jenkins?

Comment: I can't say that for certain. I haven't come across anything like that and that is about all I can say. Sorry I can't be of any help. Have you tried asking this question on Jenkins forums? Maybe they could help.